# Setting the limit of the_content characters

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to set the limit of 300 characters to the_content.

How can i set when i want to use it and when i dont ?

```
<?php   
add_filter("the_content", "plugin_myContentFilter");   
function plugin_myContentFilter($content)
{
// Take the existing content and return a subset of it
return substr($content, 0, 300);
}
?>
```

Comment: Under what conditions do you want to use it and under what not? Anyhow a simple `if()` statement around `add_filer()` will do.

Comment: This code is at my functions.php, every time i use the_content() it shows only the first 300 characters.

but in some places i want to show the entire content of the_content()

Comment: I got that from the initial question. **What** "places" do you mean - certain post categories, a specific page, etc. pp.?

Comment: Ok sry, i want to show the entire content in the single.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    function plugin_myContentFilter($content) {
        if (!is_single()) {
            return substr($content, 0, 300);
        } else {
            return $content;
        }
    }
    add_filter("the_content", "plugin_myContentFilter");

?>
```

Will shorten the content to 300 characters unless on a single post page.

Comment: hm it works, but i forgot to say i want to do the same to pages.php =/ i tried to add an else if and didnt work.

Comment: @Osmar I don't know what sort of template pages.php is in your theme, but should you mean that you don't want the shortening to happen on all static pages, change `if (!is_single()) {` to `if (!is_single() && !is_page()) {`.

Comment: @Osmar in case you saw the above comment right away, see the edit from || to && - I wasn't thinking right.

Comment: @Osmar So, they are [custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), correct? If that's the case, make use of the [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) conditional tag. Change `if (!is_single()) {` to `if (!is_single() && !is_page_template('products.php')) {`. Append one `&& !is_page_template('name_of_your_template_file.php')` per template.

Comment: @Osmar if it works fine with `!is_page()` cool. If you want it on some pages and not on others, go with the comment directly above. Glad I could help!

Comment: yeah it works fine with `!is_page('products','contact')` Thanks!